# Highcharts gauge keep tooltip visible and centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I cannot get the tootlip of my highcharts gauge to appear and stay visible and centered inside the gauge when the screen is resized.

In my fiddle you can see the tooltip appear then after a small amount of time disappear. Also, it does not remain in the center of the gauge when the window is resized.

Any help is appreciated. My [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/ujmxxf03/) is here.

```
    gaugeChartObj = new Highcharts.Chart({
        credits: false,
        chart: {
            renderTo: divID,
            type: 'solidgauge',
            marginTop: 30,
            events: {
                load: function(){
                    var p = this.series[0].points[0];
                    this.tooltip.refresh(p);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: dataC.title,
            style: {
                fontSize: '16px'
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            useHTML: true,
            shadow: false,
            style: {
                fontSize: '16px'
            },
            formatter: function() {
                return '<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><span style="font-size:1.2em;font-weight:bold;">' + this.point.series.name + '</span><br/><span style="font-size:3em;color:' + Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] + ';font-weight:bold;">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / 10, 0) + '</span>';
            },
            positioner: function (labelWidth) {
                return {
                    x: 170 - labelWidth / 2,
                    y: 125
                };
            }
        },
        pane: {
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360,
            background: [{
                outerRadius: '106%',
                innerRadius: '94%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                borderWidth: 0
            }]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickPositions: []
        },
        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                borderWidth: '12px',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                linecap: 'round',
                stickyTracking: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Subscriptions',
            borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                radius: '100%',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                y: dataC.seriesData
            }]
        }],
        lang: {
            noData: "No data to display"
        },
        noData: {
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '15px',
                color: '#333333'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can use dataLabels instead of tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/ujmxxf03/9/ if my example will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: Hi @Grzegorz Blachliński, awesome, that is what i was looking for. Please post the answer and I will upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Grzegorz Blachliński, awesome, that is what i was looking for. But there is an error in the tooltip code, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined`. Do you know why? It seems to work on the page other than this. Thanks!

Comment: It is because the tooltip right now is disabled. It is not possible to refresh it: http://jsfiddle.net/ujmxxf03/10/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dataLabels instead of tooltip to show centered information in your solidgauge chart:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.solidgauge.dataLabels

```
dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      y: -40,
      borderWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'none',
      useHTML: true,
      shadow: false,
      style: {
        fontSize: '16px'
      },
      formatter: function() {
        return '<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><span style="font-size:1.2em;font-weight:bold;">' + this.point.series.name + '</span><br/><span style="font-size:3em;color:' + Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] + ';font-weight:bold;">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / 10, 0) + '</span>';
      }
},
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/ujmxxf03/10/

Comment: perfect, for this purpose is far easier than tooltip with the callback function!

Comment: Hi, any good way to show the same when there are 2 objects of data(2 concentric gauge circles)?